# Displaying OpenStreetMap in locally hosted web page?

Tags: openstreetmap

I'd like to set up my own tile server but I'm very new to it all and do not know what to do next. I followed the guide Switch2OSM on how to install OSM locally. Surprisingly I successfully got through it after a few wrenches thrown in. Now I have no idea how to display my map in a locally hosted web page. I saw the tutorial on leaflet through Switch2OSM but its not for a local server and is very uninformative to a beginner. Any help on where to go next would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I found some hints via https://help.osm.org

[map-not-displayed-in-the-browser-and-mod_tile-folder-is-empty](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/23257/map-not-displayed-in-the-browser-and-mod_tile-folder-is-empty)

[how-to-serve-tiles-from-my-own-server](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/8371/how-to-serve-tiles-from-my-own-server)

[setting-up-my-own-tile-server](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/17225/setting-up-my-own-tile-server)

[offline-open-street-map](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/26903/offline-open-street-map)

... maybe the magic word is "localhost"?

Give us more details where you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you scai, and stephan75, I now have it working in a browser, next step is to add Nominatim.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Quick Start Guide](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html). There you will create a `L.tileLayer` object where you can just add the URL to your very own tileserver, probably starting with http:/localhost/ or the address of your webserver. That's all.